# OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server + custom membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0

1. I have a working site *aaa.com* with custom membership provider
   connected as http module.
2. I need a create OAuth 2.0 Authorization
   Server + Resource Server
3. Main scenario of using is Authorization
   Code Grant.

Here is a good example of creating what I need http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server (see source code of example)

What is my problem:

- I want to bind Authorization Server to subdomain of main site - 
  *oauth.aaa.com* and when user came from external site to my 
  Authorization Server, this server check if user is already
  authenticated on main site(*aaa.com*) and if yes - he must just press
  *Grant* button and allow external site access, if no - he must enter user name and password and after this he must automatically be log in
  to main site and Authorization Server must be authenticated too.
- I've already connected my custom membership provider as http
  module(another variant of using not impossible now) to Authorization 
  Server and *Authorize* action of this server is already authenticated
  when user already logged in to main site.
- I don't understand how I must configure Authorization Server(or create some customizations) that it can accept a cookie from main 
  site(or automatically synchronize and create a new cookie for 
  Authorization Server using info from already authenticated request).

I was try to configure *CookieAuthenticationOptions* with same cookie name as cookie name of main site and check that in cookie of main site domain is *.aaa.com* ...but nothing happend and variable *ticket* in code = null

```
var authentication = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
var ticket = authentication.AuthenticateAsync(Auth.AuthenticationType).Result;
```

Or may be I need another library, not based on OWIN? I saw DotNetOpenAuth library but seems its OAuth client, not server.